# ES5 way to format long SQL query

Tags: javascript, sql, google-apps-script, ecmascript-5

With Google Apps Script, I've some long SQL query like the following :

```
var query = "SELECT od.`product_reference`, od.`product_name`, SUM(od.`product_quantity`) AS 'cpt' " +
    "FROM `ps_order_detail` od " +
    "JOIN `ps_orders` o ON o.`id_order` = od.`id_order` " +
    "WHERE od.`product_reference` NOT LIKE ('%GIFT%') " +
    "AND o.`date_add` BETWEEN " + dateDeb + " AND " + dateFin + " " +
    "GROUP BY `product_id` " +
    "ORDER BY cpt DESC " +
    "LIMIT 10;";
```

I found it ugly, do you know a better way to format those query ? knowing that Google Apps Script provide a subset of ECMA 5 ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Is it being displayed only on the Google Apps Script IDE? Do you post it somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, with your limitation of just working with ECMA 5, shortest/optimal way to do this is with the `+`'s. You can arrange it like [@Sergey Podgornyy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5004569/sergey-podgornyy)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54417451/2678218) to make it look neater.

But here's a neat hack if you just mainly want to avoid using `+`'s. The idea is making use of *comments* that is handled and used as shown below. We're passing a function as the first argument of the method `multipleLineString`. That function is parsed to string which includes the comments in it. If you're careful enough you can make the following work:

```
var multipleLineString = function(f) {
    return f.toString().split('\n').slice(1, -1).join('\n');
}

var sqlQuery = multipleLineString (function() {/**
First Line
'Second' Line
"Third" Line (3)
**/});
```

But in your case, you have values from `dateDeb` and `dateFin` to be inserted in the query. You'll have extend this a little more to something like this:

```
var multiLine = function (f, dictionary) {
    var compiledString = f.toString().split('\n').slice(1, -1).join('\n');
    for (var key in dictionary) {
        compiledString = compiledString.replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), dictionaty[key].toString());
    }
    // Add other enhancements before return (e.g. trimming & cleaning multiple white spaces)
    return compiledString;
}

var query = multiLine (function() {/**
    SELECT od.`product_reference`, od.`product_name`, SUM(od.`product_quantity`) AS 'cpt' 
    FROM `ps_order_detail` od 
    JOIN `ps_orders` o ON o.`id_order` = od.`id_order` 
    WHERE od.`product_reference` NOT LIKE ('%GIFT%') 
    AND o.`date_add` BETWEEN _dateDeb AND _dateFin 
    GROUP BY `product_id` 
    ORDER BY cpt DESC 
    LIMIT 10;
    **/},
    {
        _dateDeb: dateDeb,
        _dateFin: dateFin
    }
);
```

Explanation for above: the second argument, `dictionary`, is kind of a "key-value pair" object so that we can define keywords in the comment (`_dateDeb` and `_dateFin`) from the first argument and their corresponding values to be replaced. Like C#'s [Dictionary](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-dictionary). But you have to be careful in building the object since JS is not strongly typed. Make sure that the 2nd argument is built properly/accordingly and the 1st argument is a function that looks similar as the above examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just format this string with ES6, then probably the best way to do so will be "template string":

```js
const query = `
  SELECT 
    od.product_reference,
    od.product_name,
    SUM(od.`product_quantity`) AS 'cpt'
  FROM ps_order_detail od 
  JOIN ps_orders o ON o.id_order = od.id_order
  WHERE
    od.product_reference NOT LIKE ('%GIFT%')
    AND o.date_add BETWEEN ${dateDeb} AND ${dateFin}
  GROUP BY product_id
  ORDER BY cpt DESC
  LIMIT 10;
`;
```

If you need to support ES5:

```js
var query = ''
  + 'SELECT '
  + '  od.product_reference, '
  + '  od.product_name, '
  + '  SUM(od.`product_quantity`) AS \'cpt\' '
  + 'FROM ps_order_detail od '
  + 'JOIN ps_orders o ON o.id_order = od.id_order '
  + 'WHERE '
  + '  od.product_reference NOT LIKE (\'%GIFT%\') '
  + '  AND o.date_add BETWEEN ' + dateDeb + ' AND ' + dateFin + ' '
  + 'GROUP BY product_id '
  + 'ORDER BY cpt DESC '
  + 'LIMIT 10;';
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using MySQL you can leverage stored procedures instead. A stored procedure is a named, parameterized query stored in the database server. Once you've deployed a stored procedure you simply call the procedure with the appropriate parameters.